# Validación de fechas Inicial y final

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda sobre como validar que una fecha final, la validación consiste en que tengo dos date, uno para una fecha inicial y el otro es para una fecha final, tengo que validar que la fecha final no sea menor a la fecha inicial.

Ayuda por favor, soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: te saludo y te doy la bienvenida, puedes por favor agregar lo que haz intentado, que errores haz tenido para que de este modo la comunidad pueda apoyarte?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: fecha final < fecha incial ? son inputs? strings? tipo Date?

Comment: En qué momento quieres la validación? Cuando se ingresa la fecha final? ¿Esta validación qué retroalimentación le da a  un usuario?

Answer (score 0):

Es muy facil de comprobar si utilizas campos de tipo `<input type="date">`, de esta manera solamente tendrías que comprobar los valores de ambas fechas.

```js
function check(){
  if(document.getElementById("inicio").value>document.getElementById("fin").value){
 alert("La fecha de inicio es menor que la final.");
}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head><title>lalalal</title>
</head>
<body>
 Fecha inicio:<input type="date" id="inicio"> <br>
 Fecha fin:<input type="date" id="fin"><br>
 comprobar:<input type="button" onclick="check()" value="Comprobar">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Erlantz, antes de responder a una pregunta asegúrate que la misma cumple las normas y es de calidad, aunque tengas la respuesta es mejor esperar a que el OP mejore su pregunta.

Comment: @LombardaArda tienes razón, lo siento, he considerado que era nuevo en JS y he intentado aportar una idea simple.